# Neo4j: How to return nodes which have a specific node in common?

Tags: neo4j, path, cypher

I am wondering how to return all the nodes with `Label_C` which have at least one node with `LABEL_A` in common if the number of the output nodes connected to such a node with `LABEL_A` is greater than or equal to a threshold. The target node can thus be reached through a path from any of the desired output nodes.

The structure is `(common:Label_A)-[:REL_1]->(:LABEL_B)<-[:REL_2]-(output:Label_C)`

My attempt:

```
MATCH (common:Label_A)-[:REL_1]->(:LABEL_B)<-[:REL_2]-(output:Label_C)
WITH DISTINCT common, output, count(id(common)) AS cnt WHERE cnt >= [THRESHOLD]
RETURN DISTINCT output
```

Look at the appended image for an example. The threshold is set to be 3.
[image]

Comment: can you share your sample/test data and expected result so that I can validate my answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added an image.

Answer (score 0):

Using size, you can build your query like this:

```
MATCH (common:Label_A) WHERE size((common)--(:Label_B)--(:Label_C)) > 3
WITH common
MATCH (common)--(:Label_B)--(output:Label_C)
RETURN DISTINCT output
```

where 3 can be replaced with your actual threshold.